# How can we prove that the sum of all elements of $A^{\displaystyle-1}$ is $5$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\displaystyle A_{5\times 5}$ be an invertible matrix whose sum of each rows equals 1. How can we prove that the sum of all elements of $A^{\displaystyle-1}$ is $5$?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $v=(1,1,1,1,1)$. Note $Av=v$. Deduce $A^{-1}v=v$. What does this say about row sums of $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_{ij}$ be the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of $A$ and $b_{ij}$ the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of $A^{-1}$. Then from $AA^{-1}=I$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 a_{ik}b_{kj} = \delta_{ij},$$ and the given condition on the rows of $A$ is that
$$\sum_{i=1}^5 a_{ij}=1$$ for each $j$. We wish to deduce that
$$\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}=5.$$

We have $$\sum_{i,j}\delta_{ij}=5$$ since $\delta_{ij}=0$ unless $i=j=1,\ldots,5$, for which $\delta_{ij}=1$. The desired equation can be obtained by summing the first equation over all $i,j$ and using the other two known equations.